# vb.net need helping in firing event

Tags: vb.net, combobox, devexpress-windows-ui

1. Combo box user makes a selection and the valuechanged fires and gives s value (that is fine)
2. I want to fire another event from a different combobox when the value in (1) is changed (this works for the click event i.e. when the user uses the mouse to select the value from 1 everything works great).
3. Issue if the user uses the arrow keys to change the selection from (1) then the event in (2) does not fire. i need it to fire

   ```
    Private Sub AgencyOriLookup_EditValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AgencyOriLookup.EditValueChanged
        cbSelection.SelectedItem = " "
        CloseCustomRange()
        cbSelection.SelectedItem = "Last 3 Months" 'Using this to fire the
        'selected value change event;
        'however, it does not fire when using the arrow keys
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbSelection_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbSelection.SelectedValueChanged

        If AgencyOriLookup.Text = "" Then
            'LabelControl4.Text = "Agency Not Selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If cbSelection.SelectedItem <> "Custom Range" Then
            CloseCustomRange()
        End If

        strDateRangeDisplayed = String.Empty
        Select Case cbSelection.SelectedItem
            Case "This Month"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Date
            Case "Last Month"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1)
            Case "Year To Date"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Date
            Case "Last 3 Months"
                Dim baseDate As Date = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, 1)
                Dim startDate As Date = baseDate.AddMonths(-2)
                deStartDate.EditValue = startDate
                deEndDate.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Date
            Case "Last Year"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 1, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 31)
            Case "1st Quarter-CurrentYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 31)
            Case "2nd Quarter-CurrentYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 6, 30)
            Case "3rd Quarter-CurrentYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 6, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 30)
            Case "4th Quarter-CurrentYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 10, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31)
            Case "1st Quarter-LastYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 1, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 3, 31)
            Case "2nd Quarter-LastYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 4, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 6, 30)
            Case "3rd Quarter-LastYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 7, 1)
                deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 9, 30)
            Case "4th Quarter-LastYear"
                deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 10, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 31)
            Case "Custom Range"
                lcidteEndDate.ContentVisible = True
                lcidteStartDate.ContentVisible = True
                lcibtnSearch.ContentVisible = True
                If _fromErrorsWarnings = False Then
                    lcicboSelectCriteria.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Always
                Else
                    lcicboSelectCriteria.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Never
                End If
                lciEndDateLabel.ContentVisible = True
                lciStartDateLabel.ContentVisible = True
                lcibtnSearch.ContentVisible = True
        End Select
    end sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing events just create a `Sub` and call it when required

Something like this (I can't test your code because is not complete):

```
Private Sub AgencyOriLookup_EditValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AgencyOriLookup.EditValueChanged

    cbSelection.SelectedItem = "Last 3 Months"
    Update()

End Sub

Private Sub cbSelection_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbSelection.SelectedValueChanged
    Update()
End Sub

Private Sub Update()
    If AgencyOriLookup.Text = "" Then
        'LabelControl4.Text = "Agency Not Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If cbSelection.SelectedItem <> "Custom Range" Then
        CloseCustomRange()
    End If
    '
    strDateRangeDisplayed = String.Empty
    Select Case cbSelection.SelectedItem
        Case "This Month"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Date
        Case "Last Month"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1)
        Case "Year To Date"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Date
        Case "Last 3 Months"

            Dim baseDate As Date = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, 1)
            Dim startDate As Date = baseDate.AddMonths(-2)
            deStartDate.EditValue = startDate
            deEndDate.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Date

        Case "Last Year"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 1, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 31)
        Case "1st Quarter-CurrentYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 3, 31)
        Case "2nd Quarter-CurrentYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 6, 30)
        Case "3rd Quarter-CurrentYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 6, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 30)
        Case "4th Quarter-CurrentYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 10, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31)
        Case "1st Quarter-LastYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 1, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 3, 31)
        Case "2nd Quarter-LastYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 4, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 6, 30)
        Case "3rd Quarter-LastYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 7, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 9, 30)
        Case "4th Quarter-LastYear"
            deStartDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 10, 1)
            deEndDate.EditValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 31)
        Case "Custom Range"
            lcidteEndDate.ContentVisible = True
            lcidteStartDate.ContentVisible = True
            lcibtnSearch.ContentVisible = True
            If _fromErrorsWarnings = False Then
                lcicboSelectCriteria.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Always
            Else
                lcicboSelectCriteria.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Never
            End If
            lciEndDateLabel.ContentVisible = True
            lciStartDateLabel.ContentVisible = True
            lcibtnSearch.ContentVisible = True

    End Select
end sub
```

Comment: @ZacharyWheeler Great!, just mark as solution.